# Помогите исправить ошибку PyScripter root.mainloop()

Tags: python

Пишу приложение:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.configure()
    root.mainloop()
```

Вроде все красиво, запускается окно Tk.
Но если я использую в PyScripter функцию 'Аварийное завершение отладки', то получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python File.py", line 9, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "C:\ProgramData\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D\19\Python 3\App\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Можно ли как-то остановить программу из PyScripter без этой ошибки?

(Пишу программу без привычной рамки, а соответственно не могу завершить из окна...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать конструкцию `try/except` над `mainLoop()`

```
try:
    tk.mainloop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: ввожу 2 раза в интерпретатор Python, результата нет.  \n >>> \n *** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***  \n self.tk.quit() \n >>> self.tk.quit() \n >>>

Comment: Надо не через интерпретатор, а в самом коде. Например добавте кнопку "Выйти" и сделайте что-бы при нажатии на нее программа вызывала метод `quit()`.

Comment: Да понятно, что если сделать кнопку и завязать на нее выход из программы это сработает, но не на всех этапах есть данная возможность.... Поэтому хотелось бы завершить работу программы из самого PyScripter, только без ошибки.

Comment: На данный момент у меня на рабочем столе ярлык bat файла с кодом taskkill /f /im Python.exe, но это не решение проблемы....

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `try/except` над `mainLoop()`:

Try:
    self.tk.mainloop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

Comment: Попробовал, ошибка ушла, но окно приложения все еще показывается и зависает, как его закрыть в данном случае?

Comment: Да, и кстати, pass уже необязателен. работает и без него.

Comment: Попробуйте после `except KeyboardInterrupt` поставить `tk.quit()`. Помогло?

Comment: Я добавил правку ответа, `root.destroy()` либо до `pass` либо взамен `pass`. работает и так и так.